# parskip setting ignored in multicols + flowfram

Tags: multicol, parskip, flowfram

I'm using static frames from `flowfram` to design a poster, and I've run into some issues with vertical spacing (notably with `titlesec`, which seems to ignore squash my pre-section spacing, but that seems to be another problem). Trying to narrow down the issue, I've noticed that `\parskip` seems to have no effect if I define it outside the frames:

```
%!TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% the frames %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[draft]{flowfram}

\newstaticframe[1]{150mm}{200mm}
                   {10mm}{10mm}[introduction]

\setallstaticframes{valign=t}
% add dummy flow frames to please the package
\newflowframe[1]{\textwidth}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe[>1]{\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\parskip}{2em} % this has no effect
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt} % neither does this

\begin{document}

\begin{staticcontents*}{introduction}
\setcounter{unbalance}{10} 

\begin{multicols}{2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat.

$$
\alpha = \beta
$$

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\columnbreak

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{multicols}

\end{staticcontents*} % end-introduction

\end{document}
```

[image]

I can't find anything to explain this behaviour in `multicol` or `flowfram`.

Comment: The culprit is staticcontent.  Note that minipage and \parbox also change the values, so possibly staticcontent is implemented using ;a minipage.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I see that I can set `\setlength{\sdfparindent}{2em}` to alter the indent. I can't find a similar setting for parskip, unfortunately :( It does appear to use minipage internally (as far as I can tell)

Comment: You could format the static frame using a savebox `\setbox\tempbox=\vbox{...}` outside staticcontents.  IIRC, you can resuse the box after staticcontents.